# PDO bindvalue in 'where in' clause doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, pdo, where-clause, bindvalue

I am trying to get a top info using an "where in" clause but if i use bindvalue or bindparam i don't get any results.

Here is my the query that doesn't give any results

```
$user2 = $db->prepare("Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id in (Select memb___id from MEMB_STAT where IP = :ip)");
$user2->bindValue(':ip','127.0.0.1',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$user2->execute();
```

If I use direct search without any bindvalues or param I get the results

```
$user2 = $db->prepare("Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id in (Select memb___id from MEMB_STAT where IP = '127.0.0.1')");
$user2->execute();
```

Can anyone help me out to use the bindvalue or param on this search 'where in' clause?

@PhilCross This is what I get when use var_dump:

```
object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(142) "Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id in (Select memb___id from MEMB_STAT where IP = :ip)"
```

Ps: I am using MSSQL Server

Comment: is `PDO::PARAM_STR` required ?

Comment: Enable MySQL query log and see what is being run

Comment: Put single quotes in your SQL query? `where IP = ':ip')`

Comment: PDO prepared statements doesn't require quotes around the values. @MandoMadalin can you do a `var_dump()` on $user2 directly after the first line in your first query? There could be a PDO error, which isn't being thrown due do your error handling. In addition, set your error handling for PDO to throw exceptions and wrap your `$db->prepare` code around a `try / catch` block.

Comment: @David, prepared statements should not have quotes around the parameters.

Comment: @PhilCross This is what i get when use var_dump: object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(142) "Select top 100 memb_guid,memb___id,mail_addr,Gender,Country from MEMB_INFO where memb___id in (Select memb___id from MEMB_STAT where IP = :ip)" Ps: i am using MSSQL Server

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Answer (score -2):

the key of the bind value should be without ':'

and the bind value should be in variable.

$ip = '127.0.0.1';

$user2->bindValue('ip',$ip,PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Not true; in fact, the `:` prefix on parameter keys used to be mandatory in older versions of PDO, now in recent versions of PDO, it is optional.